# Infinite intersection of nested subsets

Tags: real-analysis

I am struggling with the following question:

[image]

Thanks a bunch, been having a real tough time with this one.

Comment: Please do not [cross-post with MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/156630/infinite-intersection-of-nested-subsets). You should delete your question on MO, since it's off-topic, and post your *full* statement here, including the thoughts and efforts you included there (originally, this question only consisted of a link to the MO post).

Answer (score 3):

This statement is not true since
$$A_n = \left[0,1/n\right]$$
is an infinite set for all $n$
but $$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} A_n = \left\{0\right\} $$
is surely finite.